# Synchronizing sql mobile data with mysql server

Tags: sql, mysql, mobile, synchronize

We can synchronize the data from SQL mobile with SQL Server. But i need to synchronize the mobile data with mysql server. Is there any way to accomplish my requirement...?

Answer (score 2):

you should check out [sync services for ado.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002.aspx). You will need to write a bit of code, but you are able to sync with any database for which an ADO.NET provider is available. There is a MySQL provider available from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html

Answer (score 2):

Are you currently using the Microsoft Sync Framework? Whilst this is simplest to configure between a SQL CE database on the mobile device and SQL Server 2008 on the server side, it is also possible to write custom SyncProviders for other DBMS's. I've only had experience with writing a custom sync provider for an Oracle backend, and there's details on how to do this here: http://www.syncguru.com/projects/SyncServicesDemoOracle.aspx - but you can write a sync provider for any DBMS with a .net provider.